# Wordpress htaccess redirection aliases are not working

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, redirect

**I have a few links in the following format**

> - http://127.0.0.1/india/ranges/?param1=MyValue1
> - http://127.0.0.1/india/ranges/?param1=MyValue2
> - http://127.0.0.1/india/ranges/?param1=MyValue3

**Which I want redirecting to the following format**

> - http://127.0.0.1/india/ranges/MyValue1/
> - http://127.0.0.1/india/ranges/MyValue2/
> - http://127.0.0.1/india/ranges/MyValue3/

**I've added the following code in to the htaccess file, but it's not working and gives a 404 message**

```
RewriteRule ^ranges/([^/]+)/? ranges?param1=$1
```

**The full htaccess file looks like this**

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /india
RewriteRule ^ranges/([^/]+)/? ranges?param1=$1
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /india/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

To clarify, I need redirection to work like this;

`http://127.0.0.1/india/ranges/MyValue1/` > `http://127.0.0.1/india/ranges/?param1=MyValue1`

***Any suggestions for how I can achieve this using htacces or any other way?***

Comment: This question is better suited to the WordPress stack, however, it has already been asked on the WordPress site (cross-site post): https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/278516/htaccess-redirection-aliase-is-not-working

Comment: The recent edit (that you approved) conflicted with your original question... now the description in the first part of the question conflicts with the example at the end (it's the opposite way round). You also allowed the word "internally" to be removed. So, you really do want an _external redirect_?

Comment: yes, i need internal redirection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to use `add_rewrite_rule()` instead of editing your htaccess. I hate to assume, but you didn't provide any detail; if `ranges` is a custom post type (EDIT: turns out 'ranges' was a page, answer edited), then add this to your function.php file:

```
function stack_45948362_rewrite() {
    add_rewrite_rule('^ranges/([^/]+)?$','index.php?pagename=ranges&query=$matches[1]','top' );
}
add_action( 'init', 'stack_45948362_rewrite', 10, 0);
```

Then add 'query' as a query var (although I'd choose a little less generic name to avoid collision).

```
function stack_45948362_qvars($vars) {
    $vars[] = 'query';
    return $vars;
}
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'stack_45948362_qvars', 10, 1);
```

Make sure to flush your permalinks by going to Settings > Permalinks and clicking 'save changes'.

Most likely your 404 is being caused by "ranges?query=", because Wordpress is looking for an actual php page to process.

Comment: Can u please guide on which file,need to add those code

Comment: Edited my answer

Comment: Edited my answer